# Логический оператор с бесконечным количеством итераций

Tags: java, циклы, операторы

Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли такой оператор, который будет выполнять какую либо итерацию, до того момента, пока логическое условие не будет выполнено? Это не for ведь в нем надо указывать кол-во итераций, а мне нужно немного другое то, что я описывал выше. Спасибо.

Comment: в `for` не обязательно указывать количество итераций. Данный цикл вполне может быть бесконечным

Comment: Но если не написать кол-во, то цикл не будет выполнятся-выводится ошибка.

Comment: Да нуууу? О___________О  `for (;true;) { doSmth }`........https://ideone.com/ULGHOh

Comment: Чеж Вы такой злой?.. Я ж новичок, че с меня взять?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начать исполнять и продолжать пока условие верно:

```
boolean someBoolean = true;
while(someBoolean)
{
    //тут можно присвоить false для someBoolean для завершения бесконечного цикла
}
```

---

Либо можно и через цикл for вот [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540595/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9/540596?noredirect=1#comment683726_540596):

```
boolean someBoolean = true;
//в цикле for сперва идёт инициализация переменной-чсётчика, в конце действие с ней (инкрементация, например), 
//а по середине - условие - пока оно верно, цикл будет продолжаться
for (;someBoolean;)
{
    //тут можно присвоить false для someBoolean для завершения бесконечного цикла
}
```

---

Если же хотя б одну итерацию надо сделать вне зависимости от начального значения someBoolean, то можно написать так:

```
boolean someBoolean = false;
do
{
    //хотя бы раз, но выполнится
}
while(someBoolean);
```

Comment: Спасибо, давно искал.

Comment: чуть холиварный вопрос, а чем `for` не нравится? `for (;someBoolean;){}`

Comment: @pavel, вы правы, конечно) Добавил в ответ

Comment: Нет, видите ли, в этом цикле итерация производится лишь тогда, когда булевое условие верно. А мне нужно наоборот. Грубо говоря, что-бы итерация происходила до того момента, как будет достигнуто условие. Это что-то вроде цикла for, но в нем надо ставить кол-во итераций. Хотя, если это можно обойти-скажите мне.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте for для такого. Не надо. А для "обратного" есть оператор '!'. while(!condition){..}

Comment: @NikolayRomanov, почему for не использовать?

Comment: @Grundy, ну... Вроде нелогично же... =) Типа как использовать метод с 3 аргументами, вместо метода с 1)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, но ведь это же не метод :-)

Comment: @Grundy, ну да, не метод... И всё же неужто знаю про while кому-то придёт в голову пользовать вместо него этот обрезанный for?.. =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вполне, в форе удобно блок инициализации, блок после каждой итерации расположены

Comment: @Grundy, должен признаться, что не понял что вы хотели сказать(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41926/discussion-between-grundy-and-).